# Communicate from Lisp to other runtimes

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, graph-databases, ffi

Short version:

Is there a way to allow other programs to call Lisp functions of a Lisp program?

Long version:

I'm contemplating a graph database project :) Not to be started immediately, I'm only probing the ground so far. I've tried couple of graph databases, and my biggest gripe about them is they all are written in Java, (some are in C++, which isn't going to cut it either...). Java has no good way of communicating outwards. It may only be embedded inside another Java program. C++ is just hard to embed / I'm dubious that embedding was even planned.

So, I would obviously want to write it in CL, but I'm considering other options too. So, if you believe that CL simply won't do it, but you have reasons to believe that some other language will, then that's an interesting answer! My requirements to the "other language" would be that it must support parallel computing in some way. Obviously, high performance. And, as mentioned, extensibility.

Comment: If you don't concern efficiency, json-rpc is a possible solution. I often use json-rpc to bridge different programs written in different languages.

Comment: @SaltyEgg Efficiency is the primary concern :) You really don't want sacrifice any of available resourced when building a database.

Comment: Then you should use CFFI, as far as I know.

Comment: @SaltyEgg yup, that's what I'll do. I just didn't know there is a way to talk back to a C program. I'm still not quite close on how would one embed a Lisp program from C, but since the functionality is there, I'll find out (well, I guess :))

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple ways to call Lisp from other languages:

- The simplest way that should work with all implementations would be to just maintain a bidirectional stream to the REPL. So you could send commands to the REPL and receive the REPL's response. One drawback of this would of course be that everything would be converted to strings.
- You could mirror the way SLIME communicates with SWANK. In that case, you either use SWANK directly on the Lisp side and communicate through the same protocol SLIME uses, or write your own version of such a library.
- Finally, there are Lisp implementations designed with embeddability  in mind. I'm thinking particularly of [Embeddabble Common Lisp (ECL)](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) here which has a C API. For example, [this section in the manual](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/ch04s03.html) explains how to call functions, by getting hold of the function's symbol with `ecl_make_symbol` and then calling it with `cl_funcall` or `cl_apply`.

As alternatives to Common Lisp, other Lisp languages might be worthwhile to consider. Various Scheme implementations are designed to be embeddable, [this is for example the documentation of Racket's C API](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/). It seems you prefer the native code side of the runtime world over the JVM, but otherwise, Clojure is also interesting for being embeddable within Java.

For the host language there are few limits because most languages should support "pipes" (i.e. streams to other processes) or have a C FFI to call some Lisp's C API.

Comment: Yeah, I tried ECL *long ago* for something very simple, but I think I remember reading it wasn't a very efficient implementation, although I might've invented it. Would be happy to be wrong on this account. Clojure would have all the same problems any JVM language would - no extensibility. REPL is one of the major reasons I want it to be Lisp - debugging and hot-patching, but it just won't handle heavy load such as passing zillions of records around. Racket seems like an interesting option though!

Comment: I wouldn't say that ECL is terribly slow, although SBCL is, mostly, faster: http://lispm.dyndns.org/lisp/benchmarks.html You could also ask how to talk to SBCL from other programs in sbcl-devel mailing list

Comment: I've just seen that while the other way round (calling C from Java) is its more prominent feature, the JNI does also provide an API to call Java from C.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin I've asked on SBCL mailing list and here's what I've got: http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/defcallback.html which seems to fit the bill very nicely.